# database for google type searches

Tags: database, full-text-search

We need to be able to perform fast searches against 10 million tweets we have stored off. Any suggestions for a good database to use for this? We'd prefer to be able to do regular expressions searches but it's sufficient to be able to find all entries that contain a given word.

thanks - dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer at Microsoft MSDN forum - [database for bing type searches](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsearch/thread/aec97586-e286-4e2e-9d82-10f211df2ce1/)

> Full-Text queries perform a linguistic search against this data,
>   operating on words and phrases based on rules of a particular
>   language.
>
> A LIKE query against millions of rows of text data can
>   take minutes to return; whereas a full-text query can take only
>   seconds or less against the same data, depending on the number of rows
>   that are returned. We can use Full-Text Search to perform a fuzzy
>   search and then use LIKE clause to return the records that have an
>   exact match of our search conditions.
>
> For more information, please refer to the following links:
>
> Full-Text Search Overview: 
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx
>
> SQL Server 2008 Full-Text Search: Internals and Enhancements 
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721269(SQL.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/ which is used by stackoverflow and RavenDB.

Comment: Sql Server is easier for us (we're using .net) but that would be a great solution for an open source stack. Thank you.

Comment: lucene.net is for .NET. StackOverflow used SqlServer full text queries from start (IIRC) but switched to lucene to get better search results. But I do understand your point. It's a lot easier to get the index in SqlServer going.

Comment: I didn't know they had a .NET version - we'll keep that in mind if Sql Server isn't sufficient. Thanks